# Tab Url manipulation Specific tab url update

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Can i do this?

I have 2 tabs say T1 and T2 and three URLs say U1, U2 and U3
Initially, U1 is opened in T1 and on some click action U2 is opened in T2. while browsing U2 in T2 can i put a button in U2 page such that on click it opens U3 in T1 (Assuming T1 is still  open, if it is closed, then a new tab T3) ?

i am working in JSP environment. Any logic using javascript/java would do.

**Addition:**

Is there any way i can access the URL U1 ( opened in T1) inside the code(Javascript or JSP) of U2 page (opened in T2 tab)

Comment: This should work irrespective of browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JavaScript to open the new windows, you can supply a window-name which you can use to re-use the window later on.

Comment: Thats really simple. I dint know we can name tabs/windows using JavaScript. Stupid me. Thanks

Comment: This is more of another question: Is there any way i can access the URL U1 ( opened in T1) inside the code(Javascript or JSP) of U2 page (opened in T2 tab)

Comment: If the URL of all windows you have opened reside on the same domain, this could work. You need to store the handle (which is returned on window.open), and then get location.href-property. (var newWindow = window.open(..); alert("url is: " + newWindow.location.href); )

Comment: I don't know what kind of application you are writing, but have you considered working with IFrames instead?